# ElasticSearch analyzer: is there a way to remove same occurrences of words in index?

Tags: elasticsearch, find-occurrences

I'm using ElasticSearch with a custom index and search analyzer.
I'm querying users data and sometimes, there are the same occurrences in strings.

Example: "Hello World Hello Mr !" where you can see 2 times "Hello".

If I'm searching for "Hello World", I will get a better score with "Hello World Hello Mr !" than "Hello World". I don't want this behavior, even if it is logical.

So, is-it possible to remove same occurrences of words when indexing ? Example: "Hello World Hello Mr !" => "Hello World Mr !"

My current mapping and settings:

```
  settings index: { number_of_shards: 1, number_of_replicas: 1 }, analysis: {
    analyzer: {
      custom_analyzer: {
        tokenizer: "custom_tokenizer",
        filter: ["lowercase", "asciifolding", "custom_spliter"]
      }
    },
    filter: {
      custom_spliter: {
        type: "word_delimiter",
        preserve_original: "true"
      }
    },
    tokenizer: {
      custom_tokenizer: {
        type: "nGram",
        min_gram: "3",
        max_gram: "3",
        token_chars: [ "letter", "digit" ]
      }
    }
  } do
    mappings dynamic: 'false' do
      indexes :searchable, analyzer: "custom_analyzer"
    end
  end
```

Is-it possible to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add  [unique token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-unique-tokenfilter.html)  to the analyzer to achieve this.
It allows to configure such that you can remove duplicate tokens occuring at same position (ex:synonyms) or any position.